# How can I group related processes in nsolid console?

Tags: nsolid

In the nsolid console, each logical process belonging to a particular application is given some kind of process id consisting of 7 hexadecimal digits.  Our application uses node's cluster module to launch several different 'types' of worker process.  What I would like to be able to accomplish is grouping together each 'type' of worker process, ideally in such a way that I could take multiple heap dumps or cpu profiles by selecting the group.

I was hoping I might be able to use the nsolid API to have each process tag itself with its type or otherwise influence its display in the console to accomplish this. Is there any way to control the grouping or naming of processes in nsolid?

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the environment variables when launching new processes setting the **NSOLID_APPNAME** variable to a different name or you can use **NSOLID_TAGS** variable too, then you can create a custom view creating the assets for you without needing to deal with the API.

Here are the links for the docs sections explaining both topics:

- https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/4.6/docs#filtering-tagging
- https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/4.6/docs#creating-a-saved-view-with-nsolid-console